# Can canonical tags be used to make a single page rank for multiple keywords?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have a website about 'Virtualization'  and I want to rank for 'Virtualization, Desktop Virtualization, Server Virtualization and Network virtualization' keywords. I wrote a long article about these topics in my services pages and optimized those pages for these keywords.

1. Should I use my home page as canonical URL for all these pages?
2. Is this action help to rank my home page for those 4 keywords or not?
3. Is it possible to rank one page for all of these keywords?

Answer (score 2):

Use Canonical URLs if there are two pages with different URLs but the same content.

If there is a page for virtualization and a separate page for desktop virtualization and the content on both the pages is different, then there is no need to use canonical URLs.

If 2 pages have exactly the same content then set the one, you want to be indexed, as canonical.

Comment: You can optimize your pages to rank for their respective keywords and your home page for multiple keywords.